# Android Fragments, Json Parsing, return statement in doInBackground() method

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having problem when developing a weather app using Android Studio. The doInBackGround() method requires a return statement, but it shows error when I am returning forecastJsonStr (line no.181) . It says i need to return String[] and not String value. Similar return statement is asked in line 283. It says return statement missing.

```
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    //import java.sql.Time;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import android.text.format.Time;
    import static com.github.afrin14.sunshine.R.id.container;

    public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

        public ForecastFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
         }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
                FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
                weatherTask.execute("94043");
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
     container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           String[] forecastArray = {
                    "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                    "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
                    "Wed - Cloudy - 72/63",
                    "Thurs - Asteroids - 75/65",
                    "Fri - Heavy Rain - 65/56",
                    "Sat - HELP TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION 60/51",
                    "Sun - Sunny - 80/68",
            };
            List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>
    (Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

            ListAdapter mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(),
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                    weekForecast);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, 
    container, false);

            ListView listView = (ListView) 
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
            listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

            return rootView;
        }


        public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, 
    String[]> {

            private final String LOG_TAG = 
                FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

                if (params.length == 0) {
                    return null;
                }

                // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
                // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                BufferedReader reader = null;
               // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
               String forecastJsonStr = null;

                String forecastsonStr = null;

                String format = "json";
                String units = "metric";
                int numDays = 7;

                try {
                    // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                    // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast 
                    //  API page, at
                    // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                    final String FORECAST_BASE_URL = 
          "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                    final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
                    final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
                    final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
                    final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";

                    Uri builtUri = 
  Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0]).appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format).appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units).appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays)).build();

            URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7");

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Buit URI " + builtUri.toString());
            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast JSON String: " + forecastJsonStr);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

        try{
            return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
                return forecastJsonStr;
     }                                  

    /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the  
     *asynctask later,
     * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
     */
    private String getReadableDateString(long time){
        // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
        // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to 
       //valid date.
        SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM 
         dd");
        return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
     */
    private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
        // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a 
        //degree.
        long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
        long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

        String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
        return highLowStr;
    }

    /**
     * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
     * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the 
     *wireframes.
     *
     * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and 
     *converts it
     * into an Object hierarchy for us.
     */
    private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int 
     numDays)
            throws JSONException {

        // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be 
        //extracted.
        final String OWM_LIST = "list";
        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
        final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
        final String OWM_MAX = "max";
        final String OWM_MIN = "min";
        final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

        JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
        JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

        // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city 
        //that is being
        // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to 
        //translate this data
        // properly.

        // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always 
        //the
        // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
        // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

        Time dayTime = new Time();
        dayTime.setToNow();

        // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a 
        //mess.
        int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), 
        dayTime.gmtoff);

        // now we work exclusively in UTC
        dayTime = new Time();

        String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
        for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
            // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
            String day;
            String description;
            String highAndLow;

            // Get the JSON object representing the day
            JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

            // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
            // into something human-readable, since most people won't read 
            //"1400356800" as
            // "this saturday".
            long dateTime;
            // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want 
           //anyhow
            dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
            day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

            // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 
            //element long.
            JSONObject weatherObject = 
            dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
            description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

            // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to 
             //name variables
            // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
                    JSONObject temperatureObject = 
                   dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                    double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                   double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

            highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
                    resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + 
           highAndLow;
                }

                return resultStrs;
            }
            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(String... params){
                if(params.length == 0){
                    return null;
                }
            }                    

        }
    }
```

Comment: First of all you need to know what data you have to return than only one type of data should be return not multiple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first generic of your AsyncTask is defining what is returned in the doInBackground method. If you want to return a String instead of a String array (String[]) than change the async task to extend:

```
AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

and change the doInBackground Method to return String. If you don´t want it to return anything change it to "Void".

In your second <s>AsyncTask</s> doInBackground method (Why do you even have two of them?) the problem is that the method only returns something (null) when your if clause is true, otherwise nothing is returned. You should also return something in the else case.

To fully understand what the generics and return types are for I recommend you to read the [AsyncTask docummentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I want to return a string array of forecasts,so I have put String[] over there.

Comment: As far as I see you are only loading the JSON from the buffer, thats why it is only a String at this moment. You probably have to convert the JSON into a String[] before returning. Probably you should step over your code with a debugger and look step by step how your values change, or why they are not what you expect.

Comment: I also don´t understand why there are two doInBackground methods in your AsyncTask. I first thought there are two AsyncTasks, but there are not. You probably should first bring your code into better shape and come back with one specific question.

Comment: My mistake, I wrote two doInBackground methods instead of one. That is why error was arising.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized Async task with return type String array.

```
 public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]>
```

Change the initialization as below to String to make it work.

```
public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

change the method like below

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
```

Now you won't get this error. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I want to return an array of String[] forecasts, so I have written String[].

Answer (score 0):

You have to call postExecute method to get result from your http call. I have edited your code completely. This will work as you expected.

Your code should be like this.

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
            weatherTask.execute("94043");
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup
            container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
                "Wed - Cloudy - 72/63",
                "Thurs - Asteroids - 75/65",
                "Fri - Heavy Rain - 65/56",
                "Sat - HELP TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION 60/51",
                "Sun - Sunny - 80/68",
        };
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>
                (Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

        ListAdapter mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                weekForecast);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,
                container, false);

        ListView listView = (ListView)
                rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }


    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private final String LOG_TAG =
                FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();
        private int numDays = 7;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            if (params.length == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            String forecastJsonStr = null;
            String format = "json";
            String units = "metric";

            try {
                final String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
                final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
                final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
                final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";

                Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0]).appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format).appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units).appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays)).build();
                URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7");

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Buit URI " + builtUri.toString());
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                if (inputStream == null)
                    return null;
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line).append("\n");
                }

                if (builder.length() == 0)
                    return null;

                forecastJsonStr = builder.toString();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast JSON String: " + forecastJsonStr);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) 
                    urlConnection.disconnect();

                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            return forecastJsonStr;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try{
                String[] weatherDataFromJson = getWeatherDataFromJson(s);
                // do whatever you want with the output.
            }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        private String getReadableDateString(long time) {

            SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
            return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
        }

        private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
            // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a
            //degree.
            long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
            long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

            String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
            return highLowStr;
        }

        private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr) throws JSONException {

            // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be
            //extracted.
            final String OWM_LIST = "list";
            final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
            final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
            final String OWM_MAX = "max";
            final String OWM_MIN = "min";
            final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

            JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

            Time dayTime = new Time();
            dayTime.setToNow();

            int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    dayTime.gmtoff);

            dayTime = new Time();

            String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
            for (int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
                String day;
                String description;
                String highAndLow;
                JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);
                long dateTime;
                dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay + i);
                day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);
                JSONObject weatherObject =
                        dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);
                JSONObject temperatureObject =
                        dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

                highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
                resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " +
                        highAndLow;
            }

            return resultStrs;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help:)